# How to use filter with itemgetter while using the operator?

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I have a `dictionary` with `people's name` and `stock value` and I would like to get the `tuple` consists of the name and maximum value of stock. Here is an issue: some of stock value is not available and inserted as `'NaN'` and hence, I would like to filter them.

```
max_stock = max(stock.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

How can I put a filter option in the piece of code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to filter what items go into `max()`. You could use a generator expression there:

```
max_stock = max((kv for kv in stock.iteritems() if kv[1] != 'NaN'),
                key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Take into account that this can raise a `ValueError` now if there are no items left after filtering! You could use a `try...except` statement to handle that case:

```
try:
    max_stock = max((kv for kv in stock.iteritems() if kv[1] != 'NaN'),
                    key=operator.itemgetter(1))
except ValueError:
    # no stock at all
    max_stock = None
```